# Health probes optimization in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, logging, optimization, metrics

How do you actually optimize health probes in a Kubernetes cluster?

In K8s we have the following probes that we can define at pod->container level:

- Startup, readiness and liveness probes

Since application change and there is the posibillity of aggregate logs/metrics from a production cluster (for example in Azure Logs by using Container Insights) what mechanisms do you use to optimize health probes?

For example:

- In startup probes I could get the time when the container runs but only when the container enter ready state I could say that the container is ready to serve requests and this could be use to whether or not to use startup probe. An alternative would be to log the time when the application is ready and take the difference between container running and container started serving requests.
- For readiness it would make sense to adjust timeoutSeconds to better reflect the amount of time that the requests takes, but how do we measure and log this time? It's seems that kubelet do this behind the scenes withouth logging the time that it make the request and the time it took the app to respond. I could only get log data about when readiness/liveness failed but no underlying data to use for optimization.

I could make more examples but I think you got the idea. There are many k8s apps so I think there are a lot of people who already encounter this situation, have you read a blog about optimizing this? or how do you approach this optimization problem, maybe there is some tool or a paper talking about this.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to use the metrics to determine readiness/liveness?

Comment: @Turing85 I would use metrics for optimization unless there is another way that I'm missing.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "optimize". There is the concept of lifeness- and readiness-endpoints.

Comment: So liveness / readiness have parameters like: initialDelaySeconds, periodSeconds, timeoutSeconds, successThrehosld and failureThreshold. You tune those parameters according to the app. You could gather data about how long does the application respond to probes, so you tune timeoutSeconds. You also could set better values for successThrehold and failurehreshold from production data to better represent pod lifecycle. The whole idea is that whenever you have lots of pods you want your cluster to be agile, be able to respond fast to incidents, that's why I'm looking for optimization.